# Is there any way to list out the installed packages by synaptic in lenny

Tags: package, lenny

I have installed some packages through synaptic. Now I want to know  what are the packages I have installed But with out dependency packages names. What should I do to list.... 
I have used File->History but it shows with all dependency packages name.
Any one help out of this problem... 
Thanks